# WPF Click Button and Update Textblock to a new question

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Im building a Customer Service style application, I have a list of questions that we want answering with a simple "Good" or "Bad" button response, Upon the response i want the Text block to move onto the next question. I have tried

```
private void GetQuestions()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://***-***/api/v1/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = client.GetAsync("EPOS/GetQuestions").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var questionList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Questions>>().Result;

                foreach (var question in questionList)
                {
                    QuestionsBox.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas");
                    QuestionsBox.SetValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, 20.0);
                    QuestionsBox.Text = question.QuestionText;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Code" + response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }

        }
```

I cant figure out how to change the question to the next in the list from a button response.

Comment: In your current code you get a list of `Questions` from your server and go through this list with a `foreach`and write the `QuestionText` into `QuestionsBox.Text`. You always overwrite the previous `QuestionText` until you reach the end of the list. What did you try to switch to the next question? Where do you store your list of questions and the answers?

Comment: A look at the xaml would be useful, are you trying to move the answer control or are you trying to populate the question control with the next question upon submission of the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have an idea of what you're wanting from the question and it is that the answer being submitted then prompts the question to move to the next in the list.

MainWindowView:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="450" 
        Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <FontFamily x:Key="DefaultFont">Corbel</FontFamily>

        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=QuestionText}" />

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding Path=YesCommand}" Content="Yes" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding Path=NoCommand}" Content="No" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using TestWpfApplication.Annotations;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    internal class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private RelayCommand _yesCommand;
        private RelayCommand _noCommand;
        private int _questionIndex;
        private string _questionText;
        private List<string> _questions;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _questions = new List<string>
            {
                "Name your favourite football team",
                "Do you like F1",
                "Mothers Maiden Name",
                "Random Question"
            };

            QuestionText = _questions[_questionIndex];

            _yesCommand = new RelayCommand(o => Yes());
            _noCommand = new RelayCommand(o => No());
        }

        public string QuestionText
        {
            get => _questionText;
            set
            {
                _questionText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(QuestionText));
            }
        }

        public ICommand YesCommand => _yesCommand;

        public ICommand NoCommand => _noCommand;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void Yes()
        {
            // Logic for storing the answer to the question
            MoveToNextQuestion();
        }

        private void No()
        {
            // Logic for storing the answer to the question
            MoveToNextQuestion();
        }

        private void MoveToNextQuestion()
        {
            if (_questionIndex < _questions.Count - 1)
            {
                QuestionText = _questions[++_questionIndex];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How you obtain the list of questions is completely up to you and also how you store the answers will be your own implementation but from this simple solution you can see how you can cycle through the list of questions.

Comment: This is exactly what im looking for, I'll come back once implemented and show how get the questions from the DB and store them in the DB.